# Is it possible to print multiplication table using recursion with only 1 parameter?

Tags: algorithm, function, recursion

So I was searching for a way to print multiplication table using recursion and all the solution I came across were to use 2 parameters. So I would like to know if there is anyway to do the same thing but only using 1 param? (using loop is prohibited)
Expected Output:

```
n=4:
4 x 1 = 4
4 x 2 = 8
4 x 3 = 12
4 x 4 = 16
4 x 5 = 20
4 x 6 = 24
4 x 7 = 28
4 x 8 = 32
4 x 9 = 36
4 x 10 = 40
```

Here is my code:

```
public class multiTable {
    public  static  void rec(int n,int i){
        if(i>10){
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(n+" x "+i+" = "+ n*i);
        rec(n,i+1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rec(4,1);
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering if there is something we can do to use only 1 parameter (omitting "int i" from the function argument) and receive the same result.

Comment: Is hardcoding n to be 4 the solution here?  What about unrolling the loop?  Create a closure over n (and call the lambda)?  Use a member variable?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you only want to have one parameter? Understanding the reason may help produce more meaningful answers. Some options for having only one parameter are: Instantiating a table generator class, passing n as a constructor parameter, then calling the instance's `rec` method, or using a more complex type for the parameter passed to `rec`...

Comment: Hardcoding n to be 4 isn't the solution. 
Unrolling the loop seems ok but I want to know if there is other way beside that.

Comment: Do you want to add a Java language tag?

Comment: you can encode 2 numbers into single `int` easily if you are doing just first 10 multiplications then you can do `x = n*11+i` call your recursion with `x` and inside the recursive function obtain `n,i` back:  `n=x/11; i=x%11;` ... do not forget to stop once you multiplied with `10` instead of checking if `i>10` ... or use 12 instead of 11 for `*,/,%`

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the two arguments into one. The mapping is (n, i) -> (11*n+i), and the inverse mapping is (n) -> (n/11, n%11). This works assuming i is between 0 and 10, and n isn't so big that you overflow an int.

Here's the new code:

```
public class multiTable {
    public static void rec(int n){
        System.out.println((n/11) + " x " + (n%11) + " = "+ (n%11)*(n/11));
        if (n%11 < 10) {
            rec(n+1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rec(4*11+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying that this is a *stunt*.  There's no motivation whasoever for writing real code this way using recursion.  What you want to do calls for a **loop**.  Having said that...

Here's a way using a closure.  `rec` takes one argument and `func` takes one argument.  I believes this satisfies the specifications you have set out, because it is technically *"only using 1 param"*.  The function gains access to `n` by way of a closure and calls itself recursively by way of an interface.

```java
class Example {
    public interface Fn {
       void func(int i);
    }
    
    public static void rec(int n) {
        Fn fn;
        fn = new Fn() {
            public void func(int i) {
                if (i > 10) return;
                System.out.println(n+" x "+i+" = "+ n*i);
                this.func(i + 1);
            }
        };
        fn.func(1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rec(4);
    }
}
```

---

PS: this same approach would be easier in other languages: e.g. JavaScript.

```js
const rec = n => {
  const fn = i => {
    if (i > 10) return;
    console.log(n+" x "+i+" = "+ n*i);
    fn(i + 1);
  }
  fn(1);
}
rec(4);
```